# Using features (portfolio backlog) after finished in agile

Tags: tfs, agile

In case you have a Feature completed and after some time, there's a new requirement that will add value to that feature, would you use the same feature or a new one ?

Example:

```
Feature:
User Registration

User Stories:
As a Visitor I want to be able to register to the web site.
As a Visitor I want to be able to register to the web site using facebook.
As a Visitor I want to be able to register to the web site using twitter.
As a Registered User I want to be able to connect my account with facebook.
As a Registered User I want to be able to connect my account with twitter.
As a Registered User I want to be able to create a username and password for login.
```

After all those stories gets implemented, and feature completed, one month later, we have a new requirement for the registration process. (Increasing security, or add additional social login, whatever)

Should I add them to the currently finished feature "User Registration" or is it best to create a new one?

**I'm using TFS with scrum and *Feature* terminology, but it applies to any process template**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would create a new one.

Features and PBI's are time limited placeholders for desired functionality. One they are done, they are done. I'd you have new functionality that was not captured and implemented during the life of the Feature or PBI then you need a new one that is prioritised by the product owner.